# how to pass search parameters in url of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In `codeigniter`, I used get method to search the list of data.

My config are

in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 30000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

URL of my search

```
http://localhost/store/customer/index?limit=20&search_name=&search_mobile=&search_due=
```

The result is

> 404 page not found.

How to make this to work without `index.php`

Comment: is index a function in customer controller ? I means, what is controller name and method name

Comment: customer is controller and method is index

Comment: To index method i want to pass the search parameters

Comment: http://localhost/store/customer?limit=20&search_name=&search_mobile=&search_due=
Try like this

Comment: not working with this

Comment: Check without parameter, is it going to that method or not

Comment: user query string + $this->input->get()
to get the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter provides facility of clean `URLS`.You can solve problem like below.

Inside `Customer.php` controller having function `index` with parameters:

```
function index($limit="",$search_name="",$search_mobile="",$search_due="")
{
//code
echo $limit;//prints 20
}
```

Then pass arguments to function like this..

```
http://localhost/store/customer/index/20/search_name/search_mobile/search_due
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've removed index.php, drop the `/input?` from your url and just use:

`http://localhost/store/customer?limit=20&search_name=&search_mobile=&search_due=`

And do what **hamed hossani's** said and use `$this->input->get()` which returns an array. Or separately like `$limit = $this->input->get('limit');` ($limit = 20)

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get